# Remove Traiing Foward Slash using UrlRewritingNet

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, umbraco

i'm doing some work on a legacy asp.net and umbraco site. It's using UrlRewritingNet to set up rules for url manipulation.

I'd like to create a rule in the UrlRewritingNet file to remove the trailing slash from the url.

eg. http://www.test.com/index.aspx/ to http://www.test.com/index.aspx

Can you please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<add name="noendslash" 
            virtualUrl="^(.*)/$" 
            rewriteUrlParameter="IncludeQueryStringForRewrite" 
            redirect="Application"
            destinationUrl="~$1"
            ignoreCase="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this, have been looking for ages!!

Comment: This doesn't work for site root.. it keeps redirecting back to the last page.. Using Umbraco and UrlRewrite.config

Answer (score 1):

In the later versions of IIS in the url rewrite section you can set up these SEO rules without having to change code.  Just 'add rules' in the 'url rewrite' section of the website:

[image]

Comment: I know about this, but it's a legacy application, so i am not able to implement this solution, only using the urlrewritingnet file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TrimEnd()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

```
return inputString.TrimEnd('/'); // .NET 2 or newer
```

or

```
return inputString.TrimEnd(new char[] { '/' }); // legacy
```

Comment: leading != end. you want `TrimStart`

Comment: @AndrewBullock Read his question again: He says "leading", but what he wants is to remove the **trailing** slash `/` (look at the 2 URL he provided)

Comment: you're right i meant trailing slash. I also don't want to do it in code, i'd like to do it using UrlRewritingNet file.